# Why does using int instead of float as a parameter give me a wrong result

Tags: c, recursion

Whenever I define the parameter `i` in the function `exam` as an integer it always prints `Sum = 0.00`.

I would like to know why it is doing that...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float exam(float i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (i / (i + 1)) + exam(i - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Sum = %.3f", exam(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't forget about negative inputs

Answer (score 1):

If you define `i` as an `int`, the first part of the expression `(i / (i + 1)) + exam(i - 1)` is evaluated using integer arithmetics, hence `i / (i + 1)` has the value `0` and every recursive call adds `0` until `i` reaches `0`, so the final result is `0`.

Note also that the code would have undefined behavior for negative inputs as one of the calls would pass `-1` and `i / (i + 1)` would cause a division by zero which has undefined behavior and usually causes program termination.

Another invalid input is `INT_MAX` for which `i + 1` causes a arithmetic overflow.

Defining `i` as a `float` removes these shortcomings and computes the expected result.  Using `double` instead of `float` for both the argument and return type would increase the precision of the computation.

Comment: @Rix: you can accept this answer eventhough the question has been closed.